# Delayed touch down events on iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, ios11

I’ve observed that on all of my apps, there is a region at the bottom of the screen, where touch down events are delayed by A LOT. Touch up events still happen on time though. Not sure how tall the region is, maybe 40 points?

I’m guessing this has something to do with the iPhone X and safe zones. I’m not using a new phone though. Are we really expected not to detect touch downs at the bottom of the screen? That doesn’t seem right. I’m still on iOS 11.1, so maybe it’s different on later versions, but that actually doesn’t matter. Now that this issue exists I have to support it, until such a time as no one is affected by it.

So is this a problem others are dealing with? I have a workaround, which I can post when I get on my laptop. Just wanted to confirm this is a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're encountering a system gesture recognizer which is waiting to make sure that the touch is not, say, a swipe up. You may be able to fix this by implementing `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` appropriately.

Comment: Thank you sir, that sounds very promising. I’ll let you know if it works. I found a post which describes the change to iOS 11: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/avoiding-conflicts-with-system-gestures-at-screen-edges/